# How to express an integer as the sum of powers-of-two?

Tags: php, math, logarithm

I have this number:

```
0101
```

and I know it is the binary sum of

```
0100
0001
```

How can I get those values from the first one?

**EDIT**

I have create a snippet of code based on the logic by JoeCortopassi. The snippet its this:

```
protected function _getSitesPublished($value) {
    static $bits = null;
    if (!$bits) {
        $bits = array ();
        $bit = 0;
        $x = 0;
        while ($bit < 4294967295) {
            $bit = pow (2, $x);
            $bits [$bit] = $bit;
                            ++ $x;
        }
    }
    $sites = array ();
    foreach ($bits as $bit) {
        if (($value & $bit) == $bit) {
            $sites [] = $bit;
        }
    }
    return $sites;
}
```

It only create the bits the first time the method its called. I have to make the comprobation

```
if (($value & $bit) == $bit)
```

since `$value & $bit` will return an int (may be other than 0, as in `6 & 3`) and because of that I can't use only `if ($value & $bit)`

Thanks to all for your help.

**EDIT 2**
Oops! I had a little bug... forgot to increase the $x XD

Comment: Define "factor" - do you mean a value with only one bit set?

Comment: The same way you'd find factors for decimal numbers. Or do you just mean "extract all the `1` bits separately"?

Comment: @deceze yeap, I want to factorize the number. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: I don't think you mean "factorize" - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So then what is the name for that?

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: "Expressing a number as the sum of powers-of-two"?  Or "identifying positions of set bits"?

Comment: "Expressing a number as the sum of powers-of-two". That is what I want. Is there any way to do it with maths? I can figure two ways to do it programmatically, but I wish to do it with maths instead...

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: Programming **is** maths!  But seriously, the answer below is the right idea.  You just need to generalise it by using a loop, and other [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Hahaha lol, you are right, but I wish something... I don't know, slightly different. Well, I'll make the script and post it here... thanks!

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita is this for class/homework? I'm not understanding the real world use case

Comment: @JoeCortopassi I have in a database news that can be published in one site, with subdomains. I have that info stored in bits, and use mysql site_published & 4 = 4 in order to filter where to publish the news. But now, I need to export that info, I mean, all the news export where they belong. I don't code that, I'm only using it

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: As an aside, packing boolean flags into integers like that is usually not a good idea from a database-design point-of-view; it makes it hard to index and perform efficient queries.  You should consider a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_table) instead.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm considering the migration of the old system, and actually I'm doing it, but I need this working with the old system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JoeCortopassi's code:

```
$value= bindec($binary);
$sums=array();
$counter=1;
while($counter<=$value){
    if($counter & value)
        $sums[]=$counter;
    $counter*=2;
}
print_r($sums);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$values = bindec('0101');

$bar  = 1; // 0001
$fizz = 2; // 0010
$foo  = 4; // 0100
$baz  = 8; // 1000


if ( $values & $bar )
{
   //returns true
}

if ( $values & $fizz )
{
   //returns false
}

if ( $values & $foo )
{
   //returns true
}

if ( $values & $baz )
{
   //returns false
}
```

**EDIT:**

Is this more of what you're looking for? Not able to run it right now to test, but it should convey the message:

```
function bitCheck($original, $num, $return)
{
    if ( $num == 0 )
    {
        return $return;
    }

    if ($original & $num)
    {
        $return[] = $num;
    }


    return bitCheck($original, $num-1,$return);
}
```

Comment: Your answer its ok, but imagine I have 1111111111111111111... I don't like to make that lot of variables...

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita it might help us better answer your question if you give us more info, like what you are trying to solve with this. What you're talking about is typically called bit masking and is used to store settings and such.

Answer (score 1):

A Mathematica solution:

```
k[number_] := 
 ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, Length@number], # -> 1] & /@ 
 (Position[number, 1] // Flatten)
```

Gives a list of the single bit components of the binary input:

```
(* k[{1, 0, 1, 1, 0}] ->  {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}} *)
```

A Mathematica solution which takes a list of binary digits and returns a list of digit values.

```
   Clear[s];
    Options[s] := {Base -> 2, Totalled -> False};
    s[number_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
     With[{digitVals = 
        Reverse@Flatten@
           NestList[# OptionValue@Base &, {1}, Length@number - 1] number},
       If[OptionValue@Totalled, Total@digitVals, digitVals]]


(* s[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}] -> {16, 0, 4, 0, 1} *)
```

Comment: other than your answer, I don't see how this was a mathematica question at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in java, which you could use similar logic in php or mathematica:

```
public class IntAsPowerOfTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printIntAsSumPowerOf2(256);
        printIntAsSumPowerOf2(15);
        printIntAsSumPowerOf2(-1023);
    }

    /**
     * Prints an integer as sum of powers of 2.
     * 
     * @param valueToEvaluate
     */
    public static void printIntAsSumPowerOf2(int valueToEvaluate) {
        if (valueToEvaluate < 0) {
            System.out.println("Integer to evaluate must be non negative.");
        }

        int runningValue = valueToEvaluate;
        int currPower = 0;

        // Increase until larger than current value.
        while (Math.pow(2, currPower) < runningValue) {
            currPower++;
        }

        // Output sum of power of 2s.
        boolean firstOutput = true;
        while (currPower >= 0) {
            if (runningValue >= Math.pow(2, currPower)) {
                if (firstOutput) {
                    System.out.print(valueToEvaluate + " = 2^" + currPower);
                    firstOutput = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" + 2^" + currPower);
                }
                runningValue = runningValue - (int) Math.pow(2, currPower);
            }
            currPower--;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```